# Create temporary folder for ssh session only in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ssh

Is there a way to achieve this in Ubuntu:

1. When ssh session to some machine starts, special folder X is created in memory on that machine.
2. Contents of folder X and ability to interact with it are only granted to this terminal session, no one else can even know that it exists. Even the same user, which connects to this machine using another ssh session doesn't see it from that session (he sees another instance of that folder for his ssh session).
3. When session is finished in either way (normally or abruptly) the contents of a folder are automatically deleted forever and could not be retrieved by anyone.

If exactly such thing is not possible, please suggest the closest possible solution.

Comment: Not the most elegant but this works except by your 2nd requirement: ssh user@server -t 'mkdir /tmp/foo | tail; /bin/bash -i'; ssh user@server -t 'rm -r /tmp/foo'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDIR=/tmp/X_$RANDOM ; RCMD="export V1=$XDIR ; mkdir -p \$V1; trap \"[ -d \$V1 ] && rm -rf \$V1\" EXIT " ; ssh -t user@rhost  "$RCMD ;  \${SHELL}"
```

<< this ugly-looking onliner will do it

Here it is split into chunks and explained:

```
1. XDIR=/tmp/X_$RANDOM ;
2. RCMD="
2a.      export V1=$XDIR ; 
2b.      mkdir -p \$V1; 
2c.      trap \"[ -d \$V1 ] && rm -rf \$V1\" EXIT " ;
3. ssh -t user@rhost  "$RCMD ;  \${SHELL}"
```

1. A local environment variable to contain folder X path to be created on the remote host. Randomized to avoid collision with other sessions, you may also use $USER or timestamp or whatever in addition to or instead of RANDOM e.g. /tmp/someprefix_${USER}_${RANDOM}
2. A local environment variable to contain instructions to be run on remote host.
   2a. Remote env. variable V1 var to pass local XDIR value to remote host environment.
   2b. Creation of remote folder X
   2c. trap argument is an instruction to be done on EXIT signals, that icludes HUP. Means folder X will be removed on either normal exit or session break.
3. Connect to the server using prepared instructions first, then starting remote SHELL. You may want to specify it explicitly e.g. /bin/bash.